# C# moving item between listboxes no button

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Is there a simple way to move Items between two text boxes without using a button. I am using C# (in Winforms).
I have been trying something like this so that when a new item is clicked on the list it is immediately added to the other list then removed. Is there a way to keep the order of all of the items the same when moving them between the two lists? All of the other postings of similar questions selected/highlighted multiple items and then clicked a button to move them. I am hoping to immediately move any item that is clicked. I was trying to make two versions of the callback below for each listbox to move the items back and forth as an example to hopefully clarify my question.

```
private void features_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    unfeatures.Items.Add(features.SelectedItem);
    features.Items.Remove(features.SelectedItem);
}
```

Comment: I am assuming there is some way to do this with indexing that I am missing. That could keep them in order, but I was unable to even get this one to run

Comment: have you looked at the Clicked and MouseClicked events?

Comment: That worked like a charm with the same code inside, don't know still why that didn't work, but that was the perfect solution @rory.ap

Comment: private void features_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (features.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                unfeatures.Items.Add(features.SelectedItem);
                features.Items.Remove(features.SelectedItem);
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        private void features_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (features.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            unfeatures.Items.Add(features.SelectedItem);
            features.Items.Remove(features.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
```

Make sure you add the if statement so it does not crash. Run it when the listbox(named features in this case), is clicked